# Perl SOAP::LITE — How to add http request header

Tags: perl, soaplite

I have an application and want to add http header(not soap header) to it, but can not figure it out, anyone out there who can help.

Comment: I can't research a complete answer now, but basically you need to get to the Transport object. There's an LWP::UserAgent in there somewhere. Get that, and add your header to it. There might be examples in the SOAP::Lite unit tests, look at the `t/` directory of the dist on cpan.

Comment: You are right. I now can set http request head using soap service's transport object.

Answer (score 3):

I've got to set http request header using below code:

```
    my $transport = $service->transport;
    my $http_request = $transport->http_request;
    $http_request->header('x-api-key' => 'xaefdsfse' );
    $http_request->header('Content-Type' => 'application/soap+xml' );
```

Add this code before soap call.

Comment: Shouldn't it set the content type automatically?